# Why verdaccio is not supporting arm processors if node do it

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, arm, verdaccio

I'm trying to run verdaccio on my raspberry pi 3. I'm newbe with docker and I'm looking for the answer on my question.

If vardaccio docker image is based on `node:12.16.2-alpine` which supports `linux/arm` and `linux/arm64`, why it does not support ARM processors?

I'm getting an error:

```
root@DietPi:/home/dietpi/rpi-home-server# docker logs verdaccio
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Are there some required packages for linux which are not compatible with arm, installed using this command?:

https://hub.docker.com/r/verdaccio/verdaccio/dockerfile

```
RUN apk --no-cache add openssl ca-certificates wget && \
    apk --no-cache add g++ gcc libgcc libstdc++ linux-headers make python && \
    wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    wget -q https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-2.25-r0.apk && \
    apk add glibc-2.25-r0.apk
```

Or what is the reason of that? And how do you think is it possible to run it using raspberry?

Answer (score 0):

> how do you think is it possible to run it using raspberry?

[`hertzg/verdaccio`](https://hub.docker.com/r/hertzg/verdaccio) works fine on my PI 4

If you build the image on your x86 PC you must target the architecture to arm. This could help you https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx.

If you build the image on your PI Its should work. But I've not tested it.

Examples https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/docker.html#docker-custom-builds